# How to trigger a specific Dev/Test Lab environment using ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-devtest-labs

I am trying to automate the creation of Dev/Test Lab environments using ARM Templates.
Currently my environments options are stored in GitHub and lets say I have a specific environment called "Env1" that deploys PaaS services.

I wanted to use ARM Templates to trigger the creation of the environment called "Env1" passing all the required parameters.

How can I achieve this?
I was only able to find examples in Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Azure DevTest Lab environments are ARM templates already, you can either [create environments from templates in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-create-environment-from-arm#create-environments-from-templates-in-the-azure-portal) or [automate environment creation with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-create-environment-from-arm#automate-environment-creation-with-powershell).

Comment: Hi @LuisSimoes! I'm highly interested in doing the same. Do you have a sample of such a template? Or maybe you could share a procedure of how to create one?